# Why segmentation fault does not occur?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, free

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
  char *temp = malloc(11);
  strcpy(temp, "123456789");
  free(temp);
  printf("%c\n", *temp);
  return 0;
}
```

In the code above, Why don't I get segmentation fault for accessing memory that haven't been allocated. And the character printed out is empty? Shouldn't it be 1?

Comment: By using `*temp` *after* `temp` has been `free`d, you invoke [Undefined Behavior](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). A segmentation fault need not happen. BTW, you forgot to include `stdlib.h` and `string.h`.

Comment: Then will the output of dereferencing depends on the running time environment or will it always be empty character

Comment: Are you asking us to define an undefined behavior?

Comment: Undefined Behaviour is a behaviour that is undefined, *anything* can happen after it had been invoked. Just avoid it.

Comment: It could be *anything*. There is no guarantee on what the output will be once UB has been triggered.

Comment: So a segmentation fault may or may not happen?

Comment: Exactly, as well as your disk might get formatted, or the box just burns away ... ;-)

Comment: But I am accessing memory that does not belong to me, right?

Comment: Yes. That is what triggers UB.

Comment: But when the Mmu translate that address, it should generate page fault, then the kernel should handle that and find that I don't own that piece of memory and send me segv? Am I wrong?

Comment: @lplouis C is a low level language, it does not try to make the program catch every error. So there will be optimizations which will not cause a segmentation fault where this would happen in other programming languages. It just declares those situations undefined behavior. You have to make sure not to invoke that.

Comment: Why should the MMU generate a pagefault? you only marked the address as free somewhere, you don't know what it did in the cache/TLB level (probably nothing). Also why should anyone unmap the entire page when you free a single data element in it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding an element to @I3x answer.

Unlike dereferencing NULL for instance, dereferencing an address from *malloc* from the same process - even though the address has just been freed - is dereferencing an address from the virtual address space of the process, an address that is/was visible to the process a moment ago. Thus, in this case it is less likely to trigger a segfault.

However, just after *free* run, the OS considers that segment of memory unused, ready to be allocated again or even used instantly by the memory allocation system itself. This is probably why you got a different value at that location just after the *free* occured.

That segment may be allocated to another process, or made unavailable to the process that initially allocated it, triggering a page fault => segfault.

Anyway there is no reason to "cheat" the system trying to keep using an area of memory that has been given back to the OS.

Just to repeat it again: "likeness" means undefined behavior. You may not get a segfault, you may get one. Bytes may be changed, they may not. But, anyway, that memory is **not** usable anymore after a *free*. At all. Don't do it.

Answer (score 3):

Once you `free()` the pointer `temp`, its value is *indeterminate.* Accessing it is [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). There's no guarantee that undefined behaviour will result in segmentation fault.

Comment: What can you say about the output then? Does that depend on my memory usage?

Comment: @lplouis looking at the first bytes after a free, most likely makes you look at the memory allocation administration itself.

Comment: Nitpicking: "*Accessing*" might better read "*dereferencing*".

Comment: @lplouis you cannot say anything about the output, it is (also) indeterminate.

Comment: @lplouis There's no "this is how it works" explanation for undefined behaviour. What you observe might change in your next run or when you change the optimization levels or when you add more code to your program. The point is you can't determine the behaviour.

Comment: Also read: [What Every C Programmer Should Know About Undefined Behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html).

Comment: @l3x indeed. But I think there might still be some explanation that can generalize all the undefined cases